# In ASP.NET, I just want to position an Adrotator in the right top corner of my webpage.how?

Tags: asp.net, css

I just want to position an adrotator in right top corner of my webpage.Help me to position.I have the doubt, whether i have to add components before that in order to navigate to that position.And if it is not whether i can add components before that adrotator.I just want a floating layout.Help me..
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can float the adrotator above the rest of the text using css. Add your Adrotator to the top of the page (before any other controls) and add the style:

```
float: right;
```

You could also use the "top" and right properties to put it there.

```
position:absolute;
top:5px;
right: 5px;
```

Your last, and arguably best option, would be to use a proper Div layout on the page. Maybe one of these would work for you:
http://layouts.ironmyers.com/

Comment: no problem, don't forget to upvote or select as the answer if it works for you :)